# For-loop in batch file is reading the input from file incorrectly - Loops failing

Tags: windows, shell, loops, batch-file

I have a for loop reading lines from a file called "temp". It should read each line and then proceed to create a directory for each name in the file. However, it's reading the first line of the file twice before it moves to the second line. So I get an error saying the folder already exists.

The file "temp" contains, for now, two entries:

```
folder1 
folder2
```

The code is simple:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in  (temp) do  (
    set pstname=%%i
    echo the folder name is set to  %pstname%
    mkdir C:\output\%pstname%
)
```

When I run this, it reads the first line, **folder1**, from the "temp" file and creates the directory **c:\output\folder1**. So I expect that in the next iteration the variable **pstname** will be set to the second line in the "temp" file  (should be set to **folder2**)

But that is not what happens.  The loop reads **fodler1** twice and attempts to create the **folder1** folder again.  If I continue with the script it eventually reads the second line from the "temp" file (**folder2**) and creates it. So the script almost works.

Issue: What am I doing wrong? It reads the first line in the file "temp" twice before it proceeds to the next line?

Is there a next command I have to use? What is wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look again. The second directory is NOT being created.

You are a victim of the "delayed expansion" problem. The ENTIRE command from the `FOR` though to the closing parenthesis is parsed and at that time, any %var% is replaced by the value of `var` as it stands at the time the line is PARSED. Only then is the line EXECUTED.

Hence, run your codefrag once, and `pstname` as it stands at that time is used as the target directory name - possibly empty (without the rest of you code, there's no way to tell.)

What is executed is thus (assuming `pstname` is empty)

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in  (temp) do  (
    set pstname=%%i
    echo the folder name is set to
    mkdir C:\output\
)
```

BUT `pstname` will acquire the name from the LAST line of the file.

IF you then run the code again without clearing `pstname` first, then you'll get

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in  (temp) do  (
    set pstname=%%i
    echo the folder name is set to  folder2
    mkdir C:\output\folder2
)
```

which will be executed twice - once for each line in `temp` - AND create that direcory.

There are plenty of references on SO to this problem. The easiest cure is

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in  (temp) do  (
    echo the folder name is set to  %%i
    mkdir "C:\output\%%i"
)
```

(Note rabbit's ears surrounding name to be created - accounts for spaces in names)

Comment: Hi thanks - Yes . I figured out the issue - and removed the set command as you specified in ur last note. I did set the pstname to null and that worked in one script but when I placed the code inside a call command within the script .. it failed .. Is there not an easy for in in command like unix .. unix has none of these issues :)

Comment: It's not easy to see your entire script from one logical step (which is a single compound statement.) As I said, the way I demonstrated was the easiest way {to create the subdirectories from the textfile.} There are two others - invoke `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` when `!var!` becomes the RUN-TIME value of `var` (downsides: sensitivity to `!` and you've entered a `setlocal/endlocal` bracket) or use a `call` to an internal or external routine (which invokes a fresh environment block inheriting the CURRENT values.) In either of these last 2 cases, assign to `pstname` and use `%pstname%`